# How to set alarm for all calendar events synced from Google account android

Tags: notifications, calendar

I used to use my events in Google Calendar for reminding me of my events through SMS alerts earlier (when I had a simple mobile). Now I've got those synced up in my Android 2.1 (Samsung Galaxy 3 Apollo) and I would like it to remind me of my events by  alarm instead of SMSes. 
Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Log on to Google Calendar Online through web browser (I did this on PC. Not sure if these steps are available on mobile calendar site).
2. Go to Settings > Calendar Settings > Calenders > Click Notification against your specific Calendar.
3. Remove reminder for SMS and add Reminder for Pop Up.

By the above steps, whenever a new event is added on-line, it will set an alarm notification for it on mobile when synced.

For already created event, change the notification for each event to Pop Up through web browser.

Answer (score 2):

Using stock Calendar apps, you can `Press "Menu Button" > Tap "More" > Tap "Settings" > Tap "Set Alerts & Notifications"` to set the phone to ring for each reminder you've set for each events.

**EDIT:**

The stock calendar icon:

[image: icon]

*press* "Menu", then *tap* on "More":

[image: calendar menu]

*tap* "Settings:

[image: calendar more menu]

*tap* "Set alerts & notifications":

[image: calendar settings alert]

*tap on "Alert"*:

[image: choose alert]

This is on Calendar version 7 on 2.1-eclair Samsung Spica

Comment: Will that work for existing appointments or only for appointments created *after* the setting has been activated?

Comment: It will work on existing reminders; however, note that events that are not attached with a reminder does not get a notification (I never used SMS alert, but I presume it works the same).

Comment: I don't know which is the "stock Calendar" app, but I'm using default calendar app which came pre Installed and it has properly downloaded all my events and even the repeated events properly from Google Calendar. In that app, clicking on Menu directly gives Settings option and I don't see any option for "Set Alerts & Notification". I'm using 2.1 eclair.

Comment: @Ismail: I've added some screen shots

Comment: The "Set Alerts & Notification" will change the global setting however if you appointments are all set-up in gmail to notify you via SMS I don't believe you can change them all to normal notifications without doing it manually.  If you choose "Popup notification" in gmail, I believe that translates into a regular notification in Android.

Comment: From screen shots I can see that your calendar app and my calendar app differs on all screenshots. How can I know which Calendar Version I've got?

Comment: I've got a way. I will post answer by the end of day as I get time

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can setup something with Tasker.

Create a new event, based off of state --> "Calendar Entry".

Then create a task based off of it to alert a sound for you or show a dialog or whatever you need for it to do.

Comment: I don't think Tasker is a free app. And I'm satisfied with the Calendar app. just that would like it to sound an Alarm for event

Comment: Tasker isn't a replacement for you calendar, it's a way to get around having to go back and retroactively set notification manually on all your existing appointments.